# Does Providing CDN increases SEO of a website

Tags: seo, cdn

I am developing a php script and it will be free to download for the users, if use css,js files hosted in my network in the script and they install it. So every user who uses my script will load my websites css,js files.

Will that increase SEO of my website ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your ask is no !!

because its not important for **GOOGLE** and don't influence for SEO because it dont make BACKLINK for your website .

js and CSS files are'nt link

Answer (score 0):

Yes,of course .

- CDN increase your load page for users.
- CDN increase your security for users.
- CDN affect for mobile users.